# Let G be a connected graph such that |E| = 17 and degv >= 3. Find max |V|?

Tags: graph-theory

There would be 34 edges.

If we increase the vertices then we would decrease the Degree.

Hence 10 Vertices with degree of 3 and one with degree of 4.

So I think in total it would be 11 vertices am I right.

Comment: What does $|E|$ mean? At first I guessed that $E$ was the set of edges, so that $|E|$ would be the number of edges; but on the next line I read that there are $34$ edges. So now I am completely confused?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. To clarify some, you shouldn't say that if $E = 17$, then there are $34$ edges. You should note that if $E = 17$, then $2E = 34$. And so that's the right hand side for the handshaking argument.

So $3v + k = 34$. If $v = 10$, then $k = 4$. Since $\delta(v) = 3$ (the minimum degree), your other vertex must have degree $4$. Clearly $v \neq 11$, as that would imply the last vertex has degree $1$, a contradiction.

Comment: I meant to say $v \neq 11$. That was a typo. I've corrected it. If there are $11$ vertices with degree three, then there must be exactly one vertex of degree $1$, which contradicts the minimum degree requirements.

Comment: k So maximum vertex is 10 or 11 I am getting confused...

Comment: There are $11$ vertices. I am using $v$ to denote vertices of degree $3$ and $k$ to denote vertices with degree greater than $3$. So there are exactly $10$ vertices of degree $3$ and one of degree $4$. If there were more than $10$ vertices of degree three (ie., suppose $v = 11$), then you would get a contradiction as I showed.

Comment: K Got it Thank you....